# Using the coca cola logo as the calibration pattern for camera

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I am looking for camera calibration techniques with OpenCV and saw the chessboard and circles methods, but I wanted to calibrate the camera with something that is in the real world and you don't have to print (printers are also not very accurate in what they print).

Is it possible to do calibration with complex shapes like the Coca Cola logo on the cans? Is it a problem that the surface is curved?

Thanks

Comment: Printers are probably a lot more accurate than coca cola logos… Since the can is curved you are inviting a world of trouble - magnification changes with distance, there's the question of focus, and the speed at which they print these cans really doesn't lend itself to high accuracy. If you really care about calibration "Don't do it." Don't you have a real world chess board you could use?

Comment: You know it is printed on the can right?

Comment: @Floris no I don't have a chess board and I guess most people don't have one. I wanted to use something that anyone can calibrate their camera with. The easiest the better. It is uncommon to have a printer at home as well, so I wanted to use a widely accessible object for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve this is not at all necessarily a bad idea, and you are not the first one who had it. There was a technology that uses a CD, which is a strongly standardised object which at least used to exist on most households, for a simple camera calibration task. (There is little technical to be found online about this, as the technology was proprietary. [This](http://www.ieb.net/ac-2012/download/Upcload-PRESSKIT.pdf) is business document, where the use of the CD is mentioned. Algorithmically, however, it is not difficult if you know camera calibration.)

The question is whether the precision you get is sufficient for your application. Don't expect any miracles here. Generally you can use almost any object you like to learn something about a camera, as long as you can detect it reliably and you know its geometry. Almost certainly you will have to take several pictures of the object. Curved surfaces are no problem per see. I regularly used a cylinder (larger than a beverage can, though, with a simple to detect pattern) to calibrate a complete camera rig of 12 SLRs.

Don't expect to find out of the box solutions and don't expect implementation to be trivial. You will have to work your way through the math. I recommend the book by Hartley and Zisserman, Multiple View Geometry for Computer vision. [This paper](http://iphome.hhi.de/eisert/papers/vmv02.pdf) describes an analysis-by-synthesis approach to calibration, which is the way to go for here (it does not describe exactly what you want, but the approach should generalise to arbitrary objects as long as you can detect them).

Comment: This is *very* interesting. The approach with the CD is basically the same as mine. I guess they used the size of the circumference plus the inner circles?

The precision I want is under 1cm, which to my understanding is not a killer feature.

So you use a cylinder with no other recognizable feature? Thanks for the paper, I'll have a read.

Comment: My cylinder _does_ have a recognisable pattern printed on it. I just wanted to point out that curved surfaces are not a problem per se. As long as you know their geometry and are able to detect them you can account for them in the calibration algorithm. BTW, please upvote if you find the answer useful, thats what keeps SO running (upvote does not imply that you "accept" the answer).

Answer (score 0):

i can understand your wish, but it's a bad idea.

the calibration algorithm works by comparing real world points from the cam with a synthetical model ( yes, you have to supply that , too! ). so, while it's easy to calculate a 2d chessboard grid on the fly and use that, it will be *very hard* to do for your tin can, or any arbitrary household item you grab.

just give in, and print a rectangular chessbord grid to a piece of paper

(opencv comes with a pdf for that already).

don't use a real-life chessboard, a quadratic one is ambiguous to 90° rotation.

Comment: Printing for me is not a problem, but for busy people, or people that don't have access to a printer, like people on the go, I would rather find an object that exists already. This will be used in a real business case, not for research. Didn't know about the ambiguity, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

interesting idea.

What about displaying a checkerboard pattern (or sth else) on an lcd screen display and use that display as calibration pattern?? You would have to know the displaying size of the pattern though.
Googling I found this paper:

CAMERA CALIBRATION BASED ON LIQUID CRYSTAL DISPLAY (LCD)
ZHAN Zongqian
http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVII/congress/3b_pdf/04.pdf

comment: this doesn't answer the question about the coca-cola can but gives and idea for a solution to the grounding problem: camera calibration with a common object.

Comment: I thought about that @Micka, but it would require you to have 2 devices with you.

Comment: @aledalegrande that's obviously right =)
thought of something like a home solution for calibration of a webcam for example, where an lcd screen is nearly guaranteed to be existing.
Some tablet might work too, but it's still a second device. On the other side, in germany for example coca cola cans aren't so common anymore ;)